# How can I switch an image with anotherone when a list item appears in Powerpoint?

Tags: powerpoint

I am creating a presentation and I run in a weird situation!

I have a slide divided into 2 columns! On the left I want to have a bullet list whose items appear one by one as I press Enter or the right arrow key and on the right I want to have an image depending on the last visible item of the list.

That means that while I hit Enter and bullet items appear I want the image to change and I want that to happen both ways!

Does anybody know how to do that?! All that action happens in one slide! Creating 20 different slides with each "frame" isnt something I would like to do, unless of course there is no other way!

Thank you very much for your time in advance!:)

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using good animation technique in PowerPoint, its easy to do what you want. The drawback is that it will be hard for others to understand the slide outside the slideshow.
If the no. of items are less, it will be easy for you to do what you seek.
Can you post your slide here for proper understanding?

**Anyways, Try these steps if you can undersatnd:**

1. Give **Entrance** animation to **Item 1 name on left** *[On Click]*
2. Give **Entrance** animation to the **item 1 image on right** *[with previous]*
3. Give **Entrance** animation to **Item 2 name on left** *[On Click]*
4. Give **Exit** animation to the **item 1 image on right** *[with previous]*
5. Give **Entrance** animation to the **item 2 image on right** *[with previous]*

and so on . . .
* Keep the images on the right, one over the other, so that it gives the illusion of images getting replaced.
**Hope this helps**

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I'll try this, although what you said about the slideshow being hard to understand for people outside the presentation, is correct. I might choose another platform to make the presentation like captivate! Thanx a lot again!